# How to round decimal values with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, rounding

After running some code, i did get this 4D-array which i saved in a txt file, the values are quite long so i need to round them to 6 decimal places, the changes should be done in the original file, so i can have the same format of the array not just printing the values

here a part of the array

```
[[[[-0.027340000495314598, -0.07065500319004059, 0.06236099824309349, -0.11684399843215942, -0.05784200131893158], [-0.16122999787330627, -0.14122700691223145, -0.1653739959001541, 0.1630070060491562, 0.05366099998354912], [0.035610001534223557, -0.05879399925470352, 0.06178700178861618, 0.15509599447250366, -0.11066299676895142], [-0.006271999794989824, -0.04911699891090393, -0.06760299950838089, -0.005801999941468239, 0.02808699943125248], [-0.1022690013051033, -0.08862099796533585, 0.14321200549602509, -0.00038400001358240843, 0.10744699835777283]]
```

Comment: It sounds a lot easier and more robust to compute the correct precision in the step when you "run some code", rather than parsing text output and processing later.

Comment: i tried that but for some files i have about 48000 values it prints them this way 
 `0.03359864]
  ...
  [ 0.02056543  0.02923108 -0.03538683 ... -0.02362897  0.06854655
    0.01773592]
  [-0.03016991  0.00925411  0.03128474 ...  0.04443446  0.02176905
   -0.01632672]
  [ 0.0129515   0.01182471 -0.07050638 ...  0.00809885  0.00409077
    0.00621234]]

 [[ 0.00352853  0.02887471  0.02953056 ... -0.01305439 -0.03605847
    0.01689201]
  [ 0.00778143  0.02079013 -0.04591708 ... -0.00445832`  those `...` replace the values because there are too many so i thought of other method @janos

Comment: So change the code so that it doesn't print ellipses.  It really sounds like you need to ask your question about the prior step.

Comment: Do you need all `[`, `]` and `,` in desired output?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo '[[[[-0.027340000495314598, -0.07065500319004059, 0.06236099824309349' |
    perl -pe 's/([-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/sprintf "%.6f","$1"/ge'
[[[[-0.027340, -0.070655, 0.062361
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use printf for this. I found an example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167058/how-to-round-floating-point-numbers-in-shell)

`printf "%.*f\n" 6 "-0.027340000495314598"`

will return -0.027340. 6 represents the number of digits to print

Comment: yes, but i need to apply that on all numbers, i tried this  `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=sprintf("%.6f",$i)}}1' weight01.c` but each first value after `[` is rounded to `0.000000` i don't know what is the problem @Lepr